# How to send SMS on osclass user registration

Tags: osclass

I am a beginner.

I want to send a welcome SMS to a new user in osclass, adding the SMS API on each page.
If anybody knows where is the "Registration email send" I can integrate it there.

I have tried in `utils.php` but it's not working.

My Script is:

```
////SMS Start 

$name = osc_user_name();
$mobile = osc_user_phone_mobile();

$msgs = "Thank You $name, You have Successfully Registered with Classified123.";

$msgb = urlencode($msgs);

$stra ="http://sms.website.in/api/mt/SendSMS?user=user&password=pw&senderid=ABCDEF&channel=Trans&DCS=0&flashsms=0&number=$mobile&text=$msgb&route=15";

file_get_contents($stra);

/////SMS End
```